# I am trying to return OrderDates from a specific CustomerName and ProductName with the following code:

Tags: java, sql, jdbc, derby

```
PreparedStatement prep = null;

try {
    prep = conn.prepareStatement("SET SCHEMA CECS323LAB");
    prep.executeQuery();

    String query = "select OrderDate" +
            "from ORDERS O inner join ORDERDETAILS OD on O.ORDERNUMBER = OD.ORDERNUMBER " +
            "inner join PRODUCTS P on P.PRODUCTCODE = OD.PRODUCTCODE " +
            "where PRODUCTNAME = ?" +
            "and " +
            "CUSTOMERNUMBER = ( select CUSTOMERNUMBER from CUSTOMERS where CUSTOMERNAME like '%Euro%' )";

    assert conn != null;
    prep = conn.prepareStatement(query);

    prep.setString(1, "1957 Chevy Pickup"); // replace the first ? with the sanitized customer's name.
    //prep.setString(2,customerName);

    
    ResultSet data = prep.executeQuery();}
```

but I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Statement.executeQuery() cannot be
> called with a statement that returns a row count.

Comment: I can see two problems a) there should be a space between `OrderDate` and `from`  b) In `CUSTOMERNUMBER = ( select` if there is more than one rows returned it will fail. Either use `IN` or `limit 1`

Comment: You should not execute statements like `SET SCHEMA` with JDBC. Use the appropriate method on `Connection` (usually `Connection.setSchema`, sometimes `Connection.setCatalog`). As documented on `Connection`: _"Applications should not invoke SQL commands directly to change the connection's configuration when there is a JDBC method available."_

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the `.executeQuery()` after `SET SCHEMA CECS323LAB` statement. I used the `.execute()` function to fix the issue.